# Node.js execution doesn't continue after function in if-statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

This snippet of code gets executed until the end of the `getRefreshToken` function is at its last line. The `play_song` function does not get triggered. 
Am I misunderstanding the way JS works? For now I have included the call to `play_song` at the end of the `getRefreshToken` function, and of course that works as expected. However, I am very confused why it doesn't just execute function after function in the if-statement.

```
function checkTime () {
 var now = new Date();
 if (now.getHours() == time[0] && now.getMinutes() == time[1]) { 
  getRefreshToken();
  play_song();
 }
}
```

The contents of `getRefreshToken`:

```
 function getRefreshToken() {
  console.log('Starting token request')
  // requesting access token from refresh token
  var refresh_token = tokens.refresh;
  var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
  };
  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      tokens.access = body.access_token;
    }
    //play_song(); //only a temporary fix
  })
}
```

Comment: what is content of `getRefreshToken()`?

Comment: What is the relation between those two methods? What does happen when you comment out the first one?

Comment: I've added the content of 'getRefreshToken()'. If I comment out the first one, the second one gets executed normally.

Comment: Don't you get any error?

Comment: No I do not get any errors at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in JavaScript, functions are not necessarily synchronous as you might be familiar with in other programming languages. JavaScript is single threaded, however operations such as fetching data, querying API's, databases, I/O etc. all happen in parallel to the main execution of your code.

I assume `getRefreshToken()` is making some sort of network request and the fact you mentioned `play_song` works when put at the end of `getRefreshToken()` gives it away.

There are many ways to deal with this in JavaScript, [here's a good resource.](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/callbacks-promises-and-async-await-ad4756e01d90)

Here's an example for your situation, I removed some unneeded code for the purpose of the example:

```
// Using callbacks
function checkTime() {
  getRefreshToken(play_song);
}

function getRefreshToken(callback) {
  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      tokens.access = body.access_token;
    }
    callback();
  })
}

// Using Promises
function checkTime() {
  getRefreshToken()
    .then(() => {
      play_song();
    })
}

function getRefreshToken(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        tokens.access = body.access_token;
      }
      resolve();
    })
  })
}

// Using Async/Await
async function checkTime() {
  await getRefreshToken()
  play_song();
}

function getRefreshToken(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        tokens.access = body.access_token;
      }
      resolve();
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand, that the execution order of the functions is not clearly defined. However, both functions should be executed, or not?

Comment: @DustinWortmann yeah, they will definitely both get executed. Are you able to debug and step through the code line by line and see exactly what happens? Or throw a bunch of console.logs everywhere.

Comment: I've already had a lot of console.logs in there but didn't get the outputs of 'play_song()' at all. However, thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Comment: @DustinWortmann no worries, glad it works. Also be careful of nesting several callbacks and descending into callback hell ;)